# Wh-clause: what even you must condemn

Tags: subordinate-clauses, wh-questions

I saw the following sentence in a dictionary. I'd like to know whether it is correct and what relationship holds between "what even you must condemn" and "he was lying."

> But, what even you must condemn, he was lying.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this some kind of proverb?

Comment: It's an awkward example, but I think it is just a [fused relative construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun#Antecedents).

Comment: It's hard to analyze it as a fused relative clause.

Comment: I don't think it's grammatically valid. It seems to me initial ***but*** is syntactically irrelevant / discardable anyway, and what's left should be ***As** even you must condemn, he was lying.* Even then it's "awkward", but at least it would reflect the same structure as *As even you must admit, he was lying.* Which looks like a standard "fronted adverbial clause" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the meaning is

> He was lying, *a thing* even you must condemn.

But, what <sup>(a thing)</sup> even you must condemn, he was lying.

Presumably you're willing to accept hypocrisy or a degree of shady dealing, but outright lies go too far even for you.

Compare:

> But, what they did not know, I had the combination to the safe all along.

I hear this pattern quite a lot.  A variant of it is:

> But, what they did not know **was** I had the combination to the safe all along.

Comment: The variant structure is definitely correct, but I' like to know whether "What they know, John lives in New York" and "John lives in New York, what they know" are correct with the same structure.

Comment: Those examples do not have "the same structure", and they are not valid.

Comment: *What even they know, John lives in New York.*  is valid.   *What hardly anyone knows, John lives in New York* is valid.  So-called "polarity" is involved.

Comment: Does the what-clause always precede the main cause?

Comment: And what kind of polarity is involved?

Comment: The kind that licenses this clause pattern with **what**, where the clause headed by *what* precedes another clause and acts as a subject to an implicit or explicit BE predicate whose complement is a finite clause that may or may not be introduced by *that*.

Comment: You can reverse the order if you use a *that*-clause as subject:  *But that I had the combination to the safe all along was what they did not know.*  And you can omit "was what": *But that I had the combination to the safe all along they did not know.*